# displaying confidence intervals and not standardized coefficients in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code that displays standartized coefficients and not confidencce intervals. How can I show the CI instead?
Some examples iv'e seen are a bit different of a graph

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
library(dotwhisker)
library(MASS)

flights <- nycflights13::flights
flights<- sample_n (flights, 500)

m1<- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ dep_time + origin+ air_time+ distance , data = flights)
#m1<- glm(formula = arr_delay ~ . , data = flights)

m1<- stepAIC(m1)
  p<- dotwhisker::dwplot(m1)
  z<- p + 
    geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dashed")+
    geom_segment(aes(x=conf.low,y=term,xend=conf.high,
                     yend=term,col=p.value<0.05)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=estimate,y=term,col=p.value<0.05)) +
  xlab("standardized coefficient") + 
  ylab("coefficient") +
  ggtitle("coefficients in the model and significance")
  print(z)
```

Comment: Have you tried with `geom_segment(aes(x=estimate-conf.low,y=term,xend=estimate+conf.high,
                   yend=term,col=p.value<0.05))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could get what you are looking for directly from the model without using `dotwhisker`. The problem is that, since they are not standardised, the raw confidence intervals are orders of magnitude apart and don't display well on a single plot.

```r
df1 <- as.data.frame(coefficients(summary(m1)))
df1$variable <- rownames(df1)
df1$lower <- df1$Estimate - 1.96 * df1$`Std. Error`
df1$upper <- df1$Estimate + 1.96 * df1$`Std. Error`

ggplot(df1, aes(Estimate, variable, color = `Pr(>|t|)` < 0.05)) +
  geom_segment(aes(yend = variable, x = lower, xend = upper)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: hmm.. maybe i should get a table with the 95% CI and keep the dotwhisker as is

Comment: I would use profile intervals (`help("confint")`) or bootstrap intervals.

Comment: Also, if you do stepwise regression that has an impact on all statistics (including confidence intervals). Stepwise regression should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. This plot is good but maybe i can add some labels to it. I am trying to pick betweeb accurate and easy to read. indeed, automatic stepwise regression is a troublesome process.

Comment: @AllanCameron How can I add these CI as a label in the graph? Do you think it's a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

`dotwhisker` takes the `by_2sd` argument which standardizes the coefficients and confidence intervals; setting it to `FALSE` give unstandardized coefficients.  As many were confused by this behavior, the most recent version of the package (0.6) [does this by default](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dotwhisker/news/news.html).